# Using CreateSourceQuery in LINQPad

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad

How can I get linqpad to understand CreateSourceQuery in the following C# statements?

```
var airline = Airlines.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == 1776);
airline.Dump();
var crew = airline.Crew.CreateSourceQuery().Where(c => c.Title == "pilot");
crew.Dump();
```

Where Airlines.Crew is a navigation property. Linqpad gives the error:

> 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' does not contain a
>   definition for 'CreateSourceQuery' and no extension method
>   'CreateSourceQuery' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' could be found

Is this perhaps just a reference I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateSourceQuery` is an Entity Framework method. LINQPad uses LINQ-2-SQL by default.

There's a walk-through on the LINQPad website which explains how to use it with Entity Framework:
http://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx